# .htaccess : how to redirect folder to his subfolder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a web page and his url is http://wwww.example.com/category/door/

But I want to redirect (301) the http://www.example.com/category/ to http://www.example.com/category/door/ because the content of http://www.example.com/category/ is empty.

My rewrite rule is the follow :

```
RedirectPermanent /category/ /category/door/
```

But it doesn't work, because the browser redirect http://www.example.com/category/ to http://www.example.com/category/door/door/door/door/door/door/door/door/ infinitely.

An idea ? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/category/door
RewriteRule ^category/$ /category/door/ [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank, but it's not what I want because I want just redirect category/, not category/(.*)$. So I don't want redirect category/cat/ to category/door/, but only category/ to category/door/

Comment: Thank you a lot ! you solved the problem. It works perfectly. 
Thank you again and good day !